# PyCharm IDE can't find RPI.GPIO module

Tags: python, pycharm, gpio, raspberry-pi4

On the advice of TheZadok42 I installed PyCharm 2020.3.3 on both my Windows machine and my Raspberry PI 4.  I have also bought and installed the FreeNove Ultimate Starter Kit for Raspberry on both.  The first tutorial lesson is Blink.py, which just blinks an LED.  It works fine if I just run "python Blink.py".  However, when trying to run it from PyCharm it complains: "No module named 'RPI'" in reference to the line that says "import RPi.GPIO as GPIO".  How do I get PyCharm to find it?
Please note that I am not well-versed in Linux, having grown up in the MS-DOS then Windows world, so please make installation instructions or configuration file edit instructions complete.

Comment: PyCharm has its own version of Python and doesn't use the system install, you have to `pip install` packages from inside PyCharm itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can open settings, window like this, press "+" and then find add install RPi.GPIO for your project virtual env
[image: settins]

Comment: Great) Please, mark my answer as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution by Arseniy seems to be broken now, but the RPI.GPIO-def package seems to have exactly the purpose of enabling IntelliSense on PyCharm, without needing to install the full package.